# Calculate Formulas in importing excel with Laravel Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

How can I import excel in laravel excel with calculated formulas?

my code:

```
        $import = Excel::toArray(null, $request->file('excel'));
```

the result:

```
#items: array:12 [▼
        0 => "ضدعفونی کننده"
        1 => "محلول ضدعفونی کننده آتی 70% الکل 500 میلی لیتر"
        2 => 2
        3 => "AtiSpray500"
        4 => 14
        5 => "500 ml"
        6 => 1
        7 => 2
        8 => null
        9 => "=I12*I13"
        10 => 20
        11 => 2
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, It's working for me

```
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($request->file('excel'));
    $import = [$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true)];
```